# prevent click and drag in a onverflow

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a slider, everything was going alright until i put a `input` inside of it.

If i click inside the input and then drag to the right, all my content will move with the scroll, even if he is set `overflow` as `hidden`.

i made a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CqUtA/) with the problem.

here is the source:

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-content-slide">
    <div class="center-slide-content">               
        <div class="right-content">
            <div class="inside-content">
                <p>
                    Click inside the input and drag to the right
                </p>
                <p class="morrow-url-input-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" />
                </p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-content-slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2100px;
}

.right-content {
  background-color: #515151;
  width: 220px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: #285b76 0 1px 1px;  
}
```

what i'm missing, how can i prevent this ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Chromium. But maybe I didn't understand it.

Comment: try clicking inside of input, then hold and drag all to the right.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Firefox 18.0.1. Clicking in box and dragging to right; nothing happens.  Fiddle I went to: http://jsfiddle.net/CqUtA/

Comment: Are you sure the fiddle you link to is the right one ?

Comment: Which browser are you testing it on?

Comment: @JoshDM i'm using the same FF, if i click inside the input and drag all to the right, will hide the square

Comment: I see it now, the inner frame scrolls rightward, correct?

Comment: @JoshDM Chrome, FF , all up to date.

Comment: It only scrolls rightward when the entire light gray box isn't covered by the jsFiddle website inner frame; otherwise there is no scrolling, so as long as the browser window (or frame) you are viewing it in is as wide or wider than the external light gray box, there should be no scrolling.  Please confirm this.

Comment: @JoshDM The problem is that this content will be in a modal , in the middle of screen.

Comment: Similar issues? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036044/issue-with-click-drag-select-in-text-input-field-also-scrolls-parent-element-we || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900210/overflow-hidden-and-input-text-scrolling-in-google-chrome/13897395#13897395

Comment: @JoshDM look's like the problem is only in webkit, another demo: http://jsbin.com/ujozum/1

Comment: As others have said, it's just scrolling inside the div: http://jsfiddle.net/CqUtA/3/

Comment: @RicardoArruda - please confirm; I was correct in my assessment that this is only an issue when it is captured inside a jsfiddle frame that is smaller than the content shown?

Comment: @JoshDM no it is not just an issue with jsfiddle, it is an issue in webkit. If you have disabled scrolling (by going `overflow: hidden`) you can still drag the page over to see hidden content by clicking and dragging the mouse.

Comment: @JoshDM its a webkit issue, already found in the chrome issue list.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116655&q=overflow%20hidden%20drag&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary